# How can I create a custom joomla backend clone that works with the same sessions

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-component

I am trying to create a custom backend page in the same layout as Joomla. So none of the buttons have to work since I am going to be writing my own code, the only exception to that is the logout button.

How can I make the logout button work on a copied joomla backend page (in my example I copied the articles overview source code) and also make sure that when logged out this copied page is not accesible and shows the joomla login page?

I am using Joomla 3.

Comment: Can we see the work you have done so far?  Context is a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

The link below is a logout link to be used in your backend.

```
<a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_login&task=logout&' . JSession::getFormToken() . '=1'); ?>"><?php echo "Logout"; ?></a>
```